# Keep getting an error saying I should use '@string' resource for my XML on Android Studio

Tags: string, android-studio, android-xml, android-resources

I'm using Android Studio and I'm new to this.

For some of the objects like the last button object, the system tells me "Hardcoded string 'Message', should use'@string' resource". What does this mean?

I've searched online and some say to use `<resource>` but I don't know what this means. How can I fix this?

For example, in the first `ImageView`, an error pops up here `android:contentDescription="homeImage"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="135dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="138dp"
            android:contentDescription="homeImage"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            tools:ignore="ImageContrastCheck" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="136dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/followButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="88dp"
            android:text="Follow"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/messageButton"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/messageButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="72dp"
            android:text="Message"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: That means for later translation of your app it is recommended to save the string as a string resource and not hard-coded in the layout XML. You can safely ignore that at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

It's warning not an error.
And only to make it easier to reuse strings and also for translation

Answer (score 0):

It is a warning that tells you that you would better use the @string xml file to  have your texts at .

In Android studio, a resource is a localized text string, bitmap, layout, or other small piece of noncoded information that your app needs. At build time, all resources get compiled into your application.

for example your layout you are presenting above is a resource file that goes in @layout folder you also can use @drawable folder to save your images vectors ...
and there is plenty of other folders android studio provide to control your and to make it easier for you and for the system .
you might at the beginning find it hard but after some time you will like it .

for more information ,have a look at [App resources overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources)